# Что компьютер обрабатывает быстрее: векторную или растровую графику?

Tags: изображения, информатика, монитор

Для отображения векторного изображения компьютер рассчитывает формулы. Для растрового используется массив пикселей. Что лучше использовать для программы, которая будет работать на экранах с небольшим разрешением и без возможности масштабирования?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если экран пиксельный, то ответ как бы очевиден - массив пикселей. Скажу больше, даже векторная графика, при выводе преобразуется в пиксельную. За исключением устройств векторных по своей сути такие как лазеры рисующие на домах рисунки (за исключением проекторных), плоттеры, 3д-принтеры и др. Векторные экраны раньше были но сегодня вроде не применяются.

Comment: в целом да, однако если необходим upsampling-downsampling алгоритмы преобразований все равно так или иначе применяются

Comment: Ответ очевиден, если отображать пиксельную графику 1:1. Если же применять масштабирование, то ответ уже не так очевиден.

Comment: А если отбросить факт использования монитора с низким разрешением, в итоге обработка растровой графики будет легче? Например, за счёт того, что компьютер не выполняет расчёты с последующим преобразованием в растровую?